# How to use regular expressions in DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column in PowerBI that looks like this:

```
MyColumn
S01
S00
CAL
S00
S02
MOR
SIN
```

I want to create a new column that simply tells whether MyColumn is AlphaNumeric or just Alpha.  So it would look like this:

```
MyColumn  MyNewColumn
S01       AlphaNumeric
S00       AlphaNumeric
CAL       Alpha
S00       AlphaNumeric
S02       AlphaNumeric
MOR       Alpha
SIN       Alpha
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power BI and Power Query doesn't support RegEx as we know it from R, Python or other Languages. Here is an article about to use Python in Power Query for using Regex:

- [Using regular expressions in power bi desktop](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Using-regular-expressions-in-power-bi-desktop/ba-p/1744760)

Update: Another idea how we can use RegEx without Python or R is posted by Alexis Olson in the comments.

In DAX there are workarounds like the following:

```
MyNewColumn = if(ISERROR(VALUE(right(Tabelle1[MyColumn], 2))), "Alpha", "AlphaNumeric")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It's not quite native but you can also use Java Script within Web.Page to do regex without needing to install R or Python. See [here](https://www.thebiccountant.com/2018/04/25/regex-in-power-bi-and-power-query-in-excel-with-java-script/).

Comment: Thank you alexis. I've updated my post.